# scope_session doesn't have query() function?

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

```
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker())
q = session.query(table_name).filter(table_name.id==1)
```

the above code is how I use `scope_session()` and it works, but I checked the source of sqlalchemy, I found that class scoped_session doesn't have a `query()` function, but only a `query_property()`, how does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit confusing, but as well as the explicit class definition of `scoped_session`, there is also [code below that](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/699272e4dcb9aa71ebbc0d9487fb6de82d3abc2b/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py#L156) which takes all the public methods from Session and sets them as proxies on `scoped_session`.

The `query` method is one of those public methods.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know this kind of usage before.